# how to set a loop in this news api syntax

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

Hello I am currently making a voice assistant in which I have imported news api and I want to limit the number of news it speaks like I want only 3-4 news to be read by it
Below is the code:

```
elif 'news' in query:
             
            try:
                jsonObj = urlopen('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey={api-key}')
                data = json.load(jsonObj)
                i = 1
                 
                speak('here are some top news from the times of india')
                print('''=============== TIMES OF INDIA ============'''+ '\n')
                 
                for item in data['articles']:
                     
                    print(str(i) + '. ' + item['title'] + '\n')
                    print(item['description'] + '\n')
                    speak(str(i) + '. ' + item['title'] + '\n')
                    i += 1
            except Exception as e:
                 
                print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple add a list slicing to your data list

`for item in data['articles'][0:3]:`

now it will only read the first 3 articles